# Using "node-cache" module for caching data for node.js application

Tags: node.js, caching, memcached, browser-cache

I am using "node-cache" module for caching data in one of my node.js application.is there any api "node-cache" provided to check whether cache hold particular key with data or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start with checking the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cache#retrieve-a-key-get)

```
myCache.get( key, [callback] )
```

Answer (score 0):

myCache.has( key )

Returns boolean indicating if the key is cached.